# Scheduling an ActiveMQ message with a TTL, in MassTransit

Tags: c#, masstransit

I'm using MassTransit to schedule a message for later delivery, using ActiveMQ's scheduling plugin.

```cs
var provider = new ActiveMqScheduleMessageProvider(_sendEndpointProvider);
var scheduler = new MessageScheduler(provider, _bus.Topology);

var isPublishAddressFetched = _bus.Topology
    .Publish<TMessage>()
    .TryGetPublishAddress(_bus.Address, out var publishAddress);
if (!isPublishAddressFetched)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Publish address could not be fetched from " + _bus.Address);

using var combinedCancellationTokenSource = GetCombinedCancellationTokenWithTimeout(cancellationToken);

await scheduler.ScheduleSend(
    publishAddress,
    delay,
    message,
    combinedCancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

That works fine, but I don't know how to specify a TTL in this scenario (with a `MessageScheduler`). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set properties on the `SendContext` when using the message scheduler, you can create an execute pipe and pass it to the scheduler methods.

> Also, the message scheduler already has a built-in `SchedulePublish` method, so there is no reason to do all the work above – just call it.

```
DateTime scheduledTime = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);

await scheduler.SchedulePublish(scheduledTime, new Message(), 
    Pipe.Execute<SendContext<Message>>(x => x.TimeToLive  = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have another question here if you have some additional spare time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65128514/in-masstransit-if-i-set-a-ttl-for-a-scheduled-message-is-the-initial-delay-incl