# In MassTransit if I set a TTL for a scheduled message, is the initial delay included?

Tags: c#, masstransit

In MassTransit, if I schedule a message to be delivered in the future (let's say in 3 days), and I set a TTL on the message for 1 day, is the actual TTL for the message then 4 days?

If I schedule a message 30 days in the future, I'm tempted to set the TTL to 30 + 1 days, but I don't want to do that in case that adds another 30 days of TTL that I am unaware of.

Comment: I'd say it depends on the message scheduler. If using the built-in transport message delay feature, the TTL may indeed come into play. It's likely broker-specific, no "adjustments" are made to TimeToLive based upon a delayed delivery time.

Comment: This is ActiveMQ. Do you know what it does there?

Comment: I don't, you have to test to find out.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the [MassTransit repository](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/0b7ac84cccc7b95dc682b3b37589232501961ecd/src/Transports/MassTransit.ActiveMqTransport/Transport/ActiveMqSendTransport.cs), it seems like the TTL is applied upon the message being sent, rather than when it was created:

```cs
if (context.TimeToLive.HasValue)
    transportMessage.NMSTimeToLive = context.TimeToLive > TimeSpan.Zero ? context.TimeToLive.Value : TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

...
    
var publishTask = Task.Run(() => producer.Send(transportMessage), context.CancellationToken);
```

So should you set your publish time to be 1 day, until the message is sent the TTL is not considered.

Comment: But if I set it to one day, and schedule the message to arrive in 3 days, will the TTL then have it removed before it actually arrives? Just want to be 100% sure.

Comment: And I want to emphasize that this is for scheduled messages. Just regular messages.

Comment: To clarify, the TTL in the `SendContext` that you're using is applied *when the message is sent*.

Comment: But that still doesn't answer the question? I am aware that it's being set when the message is sent.